# Using modal, how to open pdf file as a popup in php?

Tags: php, pdf, bootstrap-modal

The pdf's are uploaded in the s3 bucket and by using its link, i want to display it. They are being downloaded in firefox and chrome. What to do?

```
    <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Document</h4> 
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <object data="[PDF link]">
            <iframe src="[PDF link]&embedded=true"></iframe>
          </object>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $(function () {
    var fileName = "Youpdfwithextension";//or path of pdf with extenstion
    $("#btnShow").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: fileName,
            width: 540,
            height: 450,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            open: function () {
                var object = "<object data=\"{FileName}\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"500px\" height=\"300px\">";
                object += "If you are unable to view file, you can download from <a href = \"{FileName}\">here</a>";
                object += " or download <a target = \"_blank\" href = \"http://get.adobe.com/reader/\">Adobe PDF Reader</a> to view the file.";
                object += "</object>";
                object = object.replace(/{FileName}/g, "Files/" + fileName);
                $("#dialog").html(object);
            }
        });
    });
});
 <input id="btnShow" type="button" value="Show PDF" />
  <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
  </div>
```